# Disable input field when the same input chosen ?

Tags: jquery

I have an input field ( source languages ) which i want when i click on one of the source languages, the target language with the same text is disabled

I done that so far but it keep disable the target languages when i click the source language

what i want to reset that every time .. not to make always listen to event

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/ezNxU/

```
// change the target language according to the source language 
$('#source').change(function () {

var option_source = $('select#source option:selected').text();

$('select#target option').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == option_source) $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    console.log($(this).text());
});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset the disabled property, apply it on all the options, and use a function call to set it to true / false

```
$('#source').on('change', function() {
    var self = this;
    $('#target option').prop('disabled', function() {
        return this.value == self.value;
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ezNxU/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#source').change(function () {
    var option_source = $('select#source option:selected').text();
    $('select#target option').each(function () {
        $(this).prop("disabled", ($(this).text() == option_source));
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezNxU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

use this to clear all

```
$('select#target option').prop("disabled",false);
```

so for your code : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vtyd/)

```
 $('#source').change(function () {

            var option_source = $('select#source option:selected').text();
                $('select#target option').prop("disabled",false);
            $('select#target option').each(function () {

                if ($(this).text() == option_source) $(this).prop("disabled", true);
                console.log($(this).text());
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove disable properties  on change event...that will remove disable form all option and later yourcode will add it...

try this

```
 $('#source').change(function () {
   $('select#target option').prop("disabled", false); //<-- add this line
   .....
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/ezNxU/3/)